# how to get/set variables outside of controller/module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, set

Let's say I have a predefined module/controller which sets the apple as green.

```
var _core = angular.module('_core', []);
_core.controller('mainController', function($scope, $controller, $http) {
    $scope.apple = 'green';
});
```

Can I get the apple outside of the controller? Something like.

`_core.mainController.apple`

Is this possible? I also need to set variables with external plugins, sorry I'm a complete angular noob, its a bit daunting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value to be accessible outside the controller, then you can store it in `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` and you can directly use the values stored in $rootScope where it is injectable. So the code becomes:

```
var _core = angular.module('_core', []);
_core.controller('mainController', function($scope, $controller, $http, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.apple = 'green';
});
```

Now in some other place say a factory, you can use it as:

```
var _core1 = angular.module('_core1', []);
_core1.factory('someFactory', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
  var fruit = $rootScope.apple;
//variable fruit now contains green
});
```

Comment: Let's say I have a function defined within every module, let's say it's called 'ready', how can I call that once the dom is ready, without creating a new module/factory/controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use factory to get set any module outside the controller.

```
    var App = angular.module('app', []);

    App.factory('messages', function () {
         var messages = {};

         messages.list = [];

        messages.add = function (someString) {
            messages.list.push(someString);
        };
    messages.get = function() {

};
        messages.clearList = function () {
            messages.list.length = 0;
        }

        return messages;
    });
```

And you can call this service method into your controller.

```
App.Controller('myController',['$scope', 'messages', function(scope, messages) {
        messages.add('Hello');
        var myListy = messages.get();
   }]);
```